# Windows 8 Start screen resolution

Tags: windows-8-preview

My screen resolution is 1280×1024, and I'm running Windows 8 Release Preview.

I formatted my computer and reinstalled Windows 8 CP because I had too many BSODs. When I installed Windows 8 CP and created a local account, I had 5 (or 6) tiles per column. But once I switched to the Microsoft account to get my synced wallpaper and lock-screen, the Start screen resolution changed and I got a maximum of 3 tiles per column. The size of all Metro apps including the Settings app changed and became awkwardly bigger.

Is there a way to get back 5 tiles per column? Essentially changing the resolution of the Start screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from [EightForums](http://www.eightforums.com/customization/9329-windows-start-screen-resolution.html)
Apparently I have turned on the "Make everything on your screen bigger" in "Ease of access"